# INNER JOIN with Where condition not working

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc

I have a SQL query in C# ASP.NET MVC, it works well without `WHERE` condition, but with a `WHERE` condition, it doesn't work.

Here is SQL statement:

```
string strSQL = "SELECT u.USERID, u.NAME, io.CHECKTIME, io.CHECKTYPE, io.SENSORID 
                 FROM USERINFO u 
                 INNER JOIN CHECKINOUT io ON u.USERID = io.USERID 
                 WHERE u.NAME = " + conditionSearch.NAME;
```

With `conditionSearch.NAME` is a variable from a view, I checked it, it's OK with a value need to search.

Could you please show me what is wrong in this `WHERE` condition? Thanks you!

Comment: If `conditionSearch.NAME` is a string property from viewmodel class, then you should use query parameters - avoid concatenating string value(s) into SQL statement directly from user inputs.

Comment: What is the type of conditionSearch.NAME?

Comment: Fixed with Tim's solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate fix here would be to put the name in the `WHERE` clause inside single quotes, to make a string literal:

```
string strSQL = "SELECT u.USERID, u.NAME, io.CHECKTIME, io.CHECKTYPE, io.SENSORID
    FROM USERINFO u INNER JOIN CHECKINOUT io ON u.USERID = io.USERID
    WHERE u.NAME = '" + conditionSearch.NAME + "'";
```

*However*, doing a direct concatenation to form a SQL query string is usually seriously bad practice.  A much better approach would be to use a prepared statement, with a placeholder for the name.  That is, use a query looking something like:

```
SELECT u.USERID, u.NAME, io.CHECKTIME, io.CHECKTYPE, io.SENSORID
FROM USERINFO u
INNER JOIN CHECKINOUT io
    ON u.USERID = io.USERID
WHERE u.NAME = ?;
```

Then, let your database worry about how to bind the name parameter correctly.

Answer (score 0):

> The immediate fix here would be to put the name in the WHERE clause inside single quotes, to make a string literal:

Hi Tim, Thank for reply. I tried with a exact a name have in db with single quotes, but the result still return null.

oh, but I tried with your solution ('" + conditionSearch.NAME + "'") and it work perfectly. 
Thanks you so much!